# How does CouchDB handle updating views after I update a particular document?

Tags: python, database, nosql, couchdb

I have a database of size 200mb,and around 10 views written on it.
This gives me a view file that occupies around 3-4GB on disk

All the docs in the DB get updated once everyday with an interval of a minute between each update,so number of Documents is constant.(Number of docs=number of minutes in 24 hours)

When I update a doc to it's new revision and compact the DB immediately(to delete the old rev) after,what happens with the view file?Do the values in the B-tree get updated with the new values,or is there a new entry on the B-tree,hence increasing the size of the view file?

What is the best way to handle this situation while conserving disk space and also ensuring speed of views?

Comment: It doesn't update views until you request the view again.  Have a look at the docs for `stale` for other options. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Comment: Ok,so let's say I call the view,after 10 doc updates.In that case,will the .view file grow or remain of the same size?Will the .view file replace the new entries,or just add to them,increasing their size?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498856/couchdb-view-file-growing-out-of-control